# Cheking duplicate name and insert user vb.net

Tags: vb.net, insert

I am doing a form where the user is writing his username and choose from a button list. Before the insert i need to check if the username is already existed or not. The server side code is:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'Duplicate username
    Dim username As String = tbUsername.Text.Trim()
    Dim tempUser As Byte = CByte(rblDept.SelectedIndex)
    Dim query1 As String = "Select cUserName FROM Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators WHERE cUserName = @cUserName"

    Dim haha As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(query1, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        adapter.Fill(haha)
        If haha.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            lblmessage.Text = "Error! user name is already exist"
            Return
        End If
    End Using

    'Insert new user
    Dim query As String = "Insert into Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators (cUserName,lDeptUser) Values ('" & username & "'," & tempUser & ")"
    Dim hehe As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(query, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        adapter1.Fill(hehe)
        lblmessage.Text = "User has been added"
    End Using
End Sub
```

So when the user press the button it first check the duplicate username if everything is ok, then it inserts the row.
Btw the error is occur when i press on submit button and it gave me this `Must declare the scalar variable "@cUserName".` on `adapter.Fill(haha)` line.

Please i want to know what is wrong with my code. Help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Error message shows everything you need to know to solve that issue. You're using parameter `@cUserName` in your query, but it is never set.

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
conn.Open()

Dim query1 As String = "Select cUserName FROM Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators WHERE cUserName = @cUserName"

Dim command As New SqlCommand(query1, conn )
Dim param As New SqlParameter()
param.ParameterName = "@cUserName"
param.Value = username 
command.Parameters.Add(param)

Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
```

Comment: i didn't get it. Would you please rearrange my code and put yours. I don't know where exactly i should put your lines.

Comment: Ok i knew where to put it. but the duplication is not working. i mean its not checking whether the username is exisiting or not. It just add all the usernames.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Parameter @cUserName but you did not initialize it or pass values to it.

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
conn.Open()

Dim query1 As String = "Select cUserName FROM Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators WHERE cUserName = @cUserName"

Dim command As New SqlCommand(query1, conn)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cUserName",username)

Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
```

Comment: i didn't get it. Would you please rearrange my code and put yours. I don't know where exactly i should put your lines.